# jquery page load behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've 3 page in my project

jq-scripts.js

```
// # DOM Ready
$( function() {

  $('.ttip').tooltip();

  $( '#sample_page' ).load("sample.php");

});
```

sample.php

```
  <p class="ttip" title="some text">Hallo</p>
```

index.php

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" type="text/css" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jq-scripts.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="sample_page"></div> <!-- TOOLTIP DON'T WORK -->

<p class="ttip" title="some text">Hallo</p> <!-- TOOLTIP WORK -->
```

Does anyone know why the tooltip of the loaded page (sample.php) does not work?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably initialize the tooltip plugin once the elements are actually available:

```
$( function() {
    $( '#sample_page' ).load("sample.php", function() {
        $('.ttip').tooltip();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
$( function() {
  $( '#sample_page' ).load("sample.php");
$('.ttip').tooltip();

});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fMTsW/11/)

**As i can not load sample.php page in .load(), so make innerhtml,**